# Someone recently gave me his banking information so that I could log into his account. Could I get in trouble?

Tags: banking, scams

Someone sent me their online banking information so that I could log in and check their balance. Could I get in trouble for that? I reported it to two different places that I thought I was scammed. No money was taken, moved, or sent from the account that I know of, and for sure not by me.

Comment: As long as you stay out of the account you should be fine.

Comment: This question really opens up a lot of questions that you have not addressed.  Who is this "someone" to you?  Friend, relative, co-worker, or a stranger?  Why did they ask you to do something they clearly should have been able to do themselves?  Are you sure it was THEIR account and not someone else's?

Comment: The action of you logging into someone else's account is not you getting scammed, it is potentially you willingly participating in the action of scamming someone else. You're probably being set up as the 'fall guy'.

Answer (score 9):

You’re treading on thin ice.

Banks typically go to great lengths to know their customers. They have authorisation papers to sign for setting up accounts, and don’t encourage handing credentials to others, to put it mildly.

The best case scenario would be that the person gave you the credentials to their own legitimate account. I don’t know whether merely receiving the credentials (particularly if you asked for them or willingly received them) constitutes an offence. But if they gave the same credentials to someone else as well who messed around with the account, they could blame you, and it wouldn’t look good for you.

The more likely case, however, is that they’ve given you the (stolen) credentials to someone else’s account. If you access the account, it would be an unauthorised access. You could get into a lot of trouble.

Now, there are legitimate situations where you should have view-only access to someone else’s account. The way to go about it in that case is to sign up with the bank as a signatory to that account. The bank will need the account holder to authorise you, you’d get your own set of credentials, and you can then monitor the account when you login with your credentials.

Unless you get your own set of credentials for the account directly from the bank (not one that the potential scammer emailed to you), it would be foolish to access someone else’s bank account. You can get into a lot of trouble if you do.

Answer (score 8):

Lawrence's answer is excellent; these may indeed be stolen credentials.

There's another potential attack here. Some scammers will give you "proof" they're rich in this way, by having you log in to their account on a *fake* banking site they've set up, as a way to establish trust.

You should be very wary of subsequent requests to do things like sending gift cards to people with the scammer promising to pay you back; "you know I'm good for it" sort of scenario.