# Someone asked me to log in into their bank account

Tags: scams, money-transfer, cryptocurrency, online-banking, money-laundering

For almost two months, I have been talking online to a guy who allegedly owns a mining company in Australia but works in NYC for his current job, gem dealer! Allegedly, currently, he is on a cruise ship from Paris to Greece for gems for his clients. He asked me to log in into his bank account "royal springs banking" and handle the transfer for his mining company because WiFi is bad on the ship and the transfer won’t go through on his end. I did a couple transfer for him and I have emails from the equipment company. (Which I did my research on, they are all real)

However, he now wants to send me a check of 19K and deposit it into my account, then transfer to bitcoin. This is all starting to sound like a scam. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Is this an online sugar daddy?

Comment: The bank account is probably someone else’s, and he bought the hacked credentials on the internet. Once the owner realizes his money is gone, guess whom the police will come to? Your IP address is on the logon, so maybe start looking for a lawyer…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Someone recently gave me his banking information so that I could log into his account. Could I get in trouble?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/144722/someone-recently-gave-me-his-banking-information-so-that-i-could-log-into-his-ac)

Answer (score 20):

It's a scam. Ask yourself why someone you've never met would trust you with $19,000. Also, why the 'wi-fi' on the 'cruise ship' is good enough for him to send you emails or get checks written and mailed, but is not good enough for him to do his own banking. This alleged professional guy who sells gems.

There has to be an excuse why the scammer asks someone they don't know/have never met to handle money for them, rather than do it themselves like normal people do. Being on an oil rig is a common one; a cruise ship is another. Paris is hundreds of miles inland; you can't sail a cruise ship from there to Greece. Gaping holes in the story help the scammers to filter out people who might be suspicious. You did ask him the name of the ship, and what Greek port it was headed for?

Sending a check, which you must then pass on via a non-reversible payment method is the clincher. What will happen is that you will deposit the check, which may seem to 'clear', then you transfer the funds as the guy asks, and after a shorter or longer time, your bank bounces the check so you are out all the money you sent, and if that was more than you had in your account, you now owe the bank. The bank could bounce the check because it is fake, or drawn on a hi-jacked account, or stolen, or non-valid in some other way.

The least bad thing that could happen is you lose money, but you could get in trouble with law enforcement for money laundering (what were those 'transfers'?), or involvement in fraud. Also, your bank may freeze or block your account if they see (or are told of) suspicious activity. You should report all this to your bank, and, maybe, the police. It looks better if you step forward and tell them before they come to you.

You should be aware that this 'nice guy you met on the web' (who may, in fact be a team of experienced scammers) could suddenly turn nasty if you show signs of not co-operating, and might make threats, such as saying he will turn you in to the FBI for money laundering. This is very unlikely, and your defence would be that you are a victim of deception. They may use 'the FBI' as a threat even if you are outside US jurisdiction, I heard of a Swiss guy they tried that with. Best to completely cut off this guy and block him completely. If you gave him any passwords, you should change them.

Comment: The Seine River empties into the Atlantic, so a small cruise ship **could** sail from Paris to Greece.  Really, though, it’s a scam.

Comment: @RonJohn - a really really small cruise ship, to get under all the bridges. Like a barge.

Comment: @RonJohn - and if it had a draught (or 'draft') shallow enough not to hit the bottom of the Seine, I would not like to be aboard in a lively sea, e.g. in the Bay of Biscay.

Comment: @Michael and the story becomes coherent again! How good can wi-fi be on a barge?

Comment: (@RonJohn) IIRC somewhere in CS Forester's Hornblower series the protagonist manages to get some kind of sail-powered boat (the only kind in his time) from Paris to the Channel (and meet the English fleet there). Of course, he's fictional. Like the scammer's stories :-)

Comment: From the sea at le Havre, an ocean-going cruise ship might get as far along the tidal Seine as Rouen, 105km inland, but with a severe risk of grounding if the tides are misjudged. Between there and Paris are 5 locks and weirs with a maximum sill depth of 5 metres.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a scam. When you send money from your account, as a normal, non-criminal citizen, your bank holds you responsible for it. Any money going into your account will be fraudulent in some way and will disappear at some point in time.

The result will be that you lose $19,000 and your bank *will* get that money back from you.

Comment: The bank would want $19,000 minus whatever real money was in the account, plus any overdraft and/or interest charges.